# Is there a TeamViewer for the Linux console?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, teamviewer

I have several Raspberry Pi's running DietPi (debian based) distributed in different locations. My clients are companies and everyone has a different network infrastructure.

I need to have access to my devices through ssh, but the problem is that I can't always open a port in my client's router.

There are several solutions, like reverse ssh port forwarding, but as long as I can evaluate them, they are hacks that are not very reliable.

I need to handle the possibility that the RPi might reboot, the client's router will loose internet connection for a while, etc.

So, my question is: Is there a TeamViewer like service for the Linux console? Robust, reliable and independent from the router configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for necro'ing this .. but in case someone else finds this thread via Google just as I did: Give "tmate" a try?

**tmate** - Instant terminal sharing
https://tmate.io/

How to use: You launch tmate, get an address to share with a friend, your friend connects with ssh to your session. Both of you can use terminal. Many options and self-hosted solution are avaliable.
Works on Linux / MacOS / WSL

Comment: While this software may be useful, your answer (as link-only) will be considered low quality. Please read [how to recommend software in answers](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/432690), then [improve your answer](http://superuser.com/posts/1163777/edit).

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want a terminal, maybe plain ssh is perfect for you, and working on getting it going is the real issue.

Otherwise, did you try a web search for ["TeamViewer like service for the Linux"](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=TeamViewer+like+service+for+the+Linux)?

- [TeamViewer full version - Linux](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx) from teamviewer.com. Also see the [Installation Notes](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/363-How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Linux-distribution.aspx) for terminal installation.
- [Teamviewer for Linux as a service](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1471247) - hint: use /etc/init.d or an autostart file

[Terminal Server Support in Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/330-How-does-the-terminal-server-support-work):

> ### How does the terminal server support work?
>
> On server operating systems, TeamViewer operates without any special adaptation.
>
> However, please make sure to activate the Enhanced multi-user support
>   Option (activated by default for TeamViewer 9 and later) in the
>   Options under Advanced. This option generates an individual TeamViewer
>   ID for every user who connects to the server using Remote Desktop
>   (RDP) by Microsoft as well as for the physical console. Therefore,
>   parallel and individual work of each session is possible.
>
> The Info Dialog now displays two different IDs:
>
> - Server ID:
>
>   - TeamViewer ID of the console of the server operating system (as if one were physically sitting in front of the server)
> - User ID:
>
>   - TeamViewer ID of the user logged into this server using RDP.

Comment: Hi, I don't need a visual connection, only access to the shell. my RPi isn't running X.

Comment: I believe teamviewer can be installed & run in a terminal only, see the [Installation Notes](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/363-How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Linux-distribution.aspx) from the link in my answer. I'll also edit in some info on "terminal server support" in case that's handy. Otherwise, I might not be understanding the question fully, unless the answer's just "use ssh"

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer isn't supported on ARM processors.  I've seen that there's an x86 emulation I believe called exagear that can do that and get Teamviewer on the pi... although that seems like the long way around to solve the problem.

I would solve it this way....

Setup an openvpn server out in the wild.  Make it a port that no one in their right mind would filter like 443... on the pi configure an openvpn client to connect out to it, set your work/home/laptop computers up on the same vpn and you should be able to access it behind the firewall via ssh.

You should be careful in selecting the ip range for the vpn to pick something oddball enough that you'd hardly ever run into it in the wild...  10.213.x.x or something....